# Vertically stacked Google Bar Charts

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to produce a vertically stacked bar chart using the Google Charts API and I thought I had found the solution when I found the option:

```
isStacked: true
```

However, This seems to add the stacking horizontally (see link below) and I cant seem to find a way to do it. Anyone come across this before or can help me?

**See: http://jsfiddle.net/tmA55/1/**

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you mean a vertically stacked [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)?

Just change the chart from `BarChart` to `ColumnChart`:

```
new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/tmA55/2/